# Kotlin : How to Class().fooA().fooB()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am currently taking my code skill to the more advanced level in order to achieved "easier maintain code", I got this problem

```
val attachView = Custom()
    attachView.setRoot(root)
    attachView.setAdded(add)
    attachView.build()
```

Those code, as you can see I repeatedly calling attachView over and over again. it works fine, but I want it to be more compact by eliminating calling attachView multiple time. My final aim is just like this

```
Custom().setRoot().setAdded().build()
```

is there any method that I must to know in order to build something like that ?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No external method will give you such semantics:

```
Custom().setRoot().setAdded().build()
```

It can be achieved by changing the internals of `Customer` class. So that the `setRoot()` and `setAdded()` will return `this`. Like `fun setRoot(root: Root): Custom`, etc.

With Kotlin you can use several functions to avoid adding `attachView.` before methods call. Like

-with

```
with(Custom()) {
    setRoot(root)
    setAdded(add)
    build()
}
```

-apply

```
Custom().apply {
    setRoot(root)
    setAdded(add)
    build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val attachView = Custom().apply {
   setRoot(root)
   setAdded(add)
   build()
}
```

If you really want a one-liner you can do this

```
 val attachView = Custom().apply { setRoot(root); setAdded(add); build() }
```